# Design Question (Ruby On Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my system there are many types of users (4), based on the user that is logged in they have access to only certain information.

For example I am trying to do something like this in my Client model:

```
 class Client
     def self.allowed
        if current_user.is_a?(SuperAdmin)
          return self.all
        elsif current_user.is_a?(Client)
          return [current_user]
        elsif current_user.is_a?(ClientAdmin)
          return [current_user.client]
        end
      end
   end
```

The problem is, it seems my model doesn't have access to the current_user helper method. (undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #)

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I fix this
2. Should logic such as getting back the allowed client be done in the model?

Comment: Could you paste the error? 

and you should not to use the "return", just pass what it should return that rails will understand. Just a tip.

Comment: undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<Class:0x106832910>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your methodology, I would define the method to allow passing in a user to check, as follows:

```
class Client
   def self.allowed(user)
      if user.is_a?(SuperAdmin)
        return self.all
      elsif user.is_a?(Client)
        return [user]
      elsif user.is_a?(ClientAdmin)
        return [user.client]
      end
    end
 end
```

Then, your controllers can decide which user should be checked based on the action being performed (although this will usually be `current_user`, this will free up your implementation to work with *any* user, so if you decide to add functionaly that depends on that fact later you're covered).

That being said, you should take at an authorization library; I personally really like [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan). It allows you to define authorizations in one place, using a style similar to the one you present here. The author, Ryan Bates, has a [great screencast on using CanCan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan).

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How can I fix this

I can't tell without seeing how you're attempting to access the method, but you might consider the following in your `ApplicationController`:

```
before_filter :set_current_user

def set_current_user
  Client.current_user = current_user
end
```

This provides a copy of the `current_user` in your `Client` model.

> 2. Should logic such as getting back the allowed client be done in the model?

Most authentication systems I've used have placed the `current_user` (or equivalent function) in the `ApplicationController`, and provided methods to protect specific controller actions from access by unauthorized users. After all it's the controllers that should decide which users are able to access their actions, not the models.

Generally speaking, if you're trying to access members/methods of your controller from within your model, you're doing it wrong - that's not how information is supposed to flow through an MVC app.